# I get an error message "cannot import 'urlopen' from 'urllib' running python3 on a Mac with Beautiful Soup installed

Tags: import, urllib, urlopen

I can't run this code "from urlopen import urllib" on a Mac using Beautiful Soup to do web scraping.

I have installed Beautiful Soup and imported it along with requests and lxml.

> > > from urllib import urlopen
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: cannot import name 'urlopen' from 'urllib' (/Users/reb/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/**init**.py)

I don't expect any immediately visible result, just urlopen being available to use.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("http://www.google.com/")
print(html)
```

You should import `urlopen` from `urllib.request` in python3